# Optimizing percentage calculation SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
------------------
sl no | Error type
------------------
1     | err1
------------------
2     | err2
------------------
3     | err1
------------------
4     | err2
------------------
5     | err2
------------------
6     | err3
------------------
```

Result I want:

```
---------------------------
Error type | Count | %
---------------------------
err1       | 2     | 33.33
---------------------------
err2       | 3     | 50
---------------------------
err3       | 1     | 16.66
---------------------------
```

I'm using following query to get above result:

```
select 
    error as Error,
    count(*) as Count, 
    100* count(*)/(select count(*) from logs) as Percentage 
from logs 
group by error;
```

Is it optimized for the task? If not, what are some other efficient ways I can get that information?

Comment: Is your concern the `select count(*) from logs` subquery? Or do you have another concern?

Comment: Does it run quickly enough for you? Don't worry about efficiency unless it becomes a problem.

Comment: @DaveZych My table will be around 4Million records, So having a efficeint solution will save me lots of time and money.

Comment: @Abhijeet 4M records is really, well, not that many unless they're very wide records. Your original query is fine and a cross-join is unnecessary unless you want to make your query look more complicated - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will perform the `count(*)` per row. I'd query it once, and cross join it to the individual counts:

```
SELECT     a.error, a.cnt, 100 * a.cnt / b.total_count AS percentage
FROM       (SELECT   error, COUNT(*) as cnt
            FROM     logs
            GROUP BY error) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM logs) b
```

Comment: This is incorrect, in that `count(*)` will not be executed once per row in the original query. This will be optimized away in the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what DBMS you're using. If your DBMS allows you to use aggregate functions as window functions (you can do this in Oracle), then you can do the following:

```
SELECT error, COUNT(*) AS count, 100*COUNT(*)/COUNT(*) OVER ( ) AS percentage
  FROM logs
 GROUP BY error
```

(Note that the OVER( ) clause is empty to indicate that the total count is what is wanted.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using mysql server. :(

Comment: Please try to tag your questions appropriately in the future ... always helps for others to know which DBMS you're using!

Answer (score 0):

Before you go and try to optimize any query, you should review the execution plan.  For example, in MSSQL, the query plan will look something like this:

[image: Query Plan]

You can very clearly see two index scans (top and bottom branches to the right of "Nested Loops").  The top branch is performing your `count(*)` aggregate to get the total number of rows in the table.  This is done once, and the resulting single row containing the count is paired with each of the rows in the bottom branch.  The bottom branch is performing the `count` aggregate for each group.

So without changing your highly readable query, you likely already have an efficient execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I was under impresession that 'select count(*) from logs' will run for each line in outer table.